# is there any reason to avoid editing /etc/group directly

Tags: useradd

I find it much easier to edit files directly rather than remember commands like useradd -g, usermod, groupmod, etc.  Is there anything wrong with just editing /etc/group directly?

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/8950/22142

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Editing the `group`, `passwd`, and `shadow` files directly is safe, but in order to do so you should use the `vigr` and `vipw` commands.

When using `vigr` or `vipw`, locks are applied to the files in order to prevent concurrent editing which can lead to file corruption.

Comment: Can you also come up with a `vishadow` to edit /etc/shadow that way?

Comment: Usually you should NEVER edit the `/etc/shadow` file directly.

Comment: @ott--: Sometimes editing the `/etc/shadow` file directly is necessary or desirable. Some variants of `vipw` support a `-s` option to do so. Just be careful and make sure you understand what you are doing. Read [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-etcshadow-file/) or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from not making mistakes while doing so, you have to be aware that on systems where LDAP is setup `useradd` etc. can also update the data there.

Essentially if only `/etc/group`, and only a limited amount of lines in there,  are effected you might as well edit the file.

If you have `/etc` under revision control (`mercurial`, `git`) it is easy to roll-back changes.