# How do I put comments in my /etc/shadow file?

Tags: password

I am running through some system upgrades and my package manager is showing changes between the upstream /etc/shadow and mine.

I would like to put some comments in the file for next time this happens.  How would I accomplish putting comments in the /etc/shadow file without breaking things.

I am thinking default "#" would likely do it, but if I get this wrong the reboot won't be that enjoyable.

Comment: Use [etckeeper](https://joeyh.name/code/etckeeper/) and record your comments in commit messages.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On Linux systems using GNU libc, lines starting with `#` are ignored in `/etc/shadow`. The parsing is done by `__fgetspent_r()`, and its [source code](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=shadow/fgetspent_r.c) explicitly handles (and documents) this behaviour.

So on the vast majority of Linux systems you can comment lines in `/etc/shadow` with `#` without causing problems.

Unfortunately comments are dropped when `/etc/shadow` is updated, *e.g.* by `passwd`; so storing comments isn't actually safe (from the comments' point of view).

This means you need to find somewhere else to store your comments: two good suggestions are [dr01](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/34039/dr01)'s [idea](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/206780/86440) of using `/etc/shadow.README`, or better yet [Gilles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/885/gilles)' [idea](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206730/how-do-i-put-comments-in-my-etc-shadow-file/206835#comment349128_206730) of using commit messages with [etckeeper](https://joeyh.name/code/etckeeper/).

Comment: Just about _any_ invalid entry appears to get lost with `passwd`. I tried using a bogus user entry, or a valid one and adding characters to the final entry, but all to no avail.

Answer (score 8):

Every line of `/etc/shadow` is considered as a user record. As [written](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/206835/86440) by Stephen Kitt who reviewed the parser's source code, you can put lines starting with `#` as comments in the file or even empty lines and they will be ignored.

However, I have never seen a `/etc/shadow` file with comments on it. It appears it is not common practice, and for a very good reason: [editing it by hand is strongly discouraged](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/190241/why-should-you-never-edit-the-etc-shadow-file-directly). For this reason, I'd rather suggest you create a `/etc/shadow.README` file instead to store your comments. Remember to `chmod 000` the file to avoid non-root users snooping on it.

Comment: So why `000`? Owned by `root:root` and then `ug=r,o=` not enough?

Comment: 000 are the permissions of `/etc/shadow` (at least on Red Hat, I haven't looked in other distros) and ensure that only root has access to the file.  440, as you suggest, make the file readable by a regular user should he/she join by mistake the root group.  On a properly administered machine, and for all practical purposes, they're worth the same.  I think that 000 better conveys a meaning of "security critical file - keep hands off", but that's just my opinion.

Comment: @dr01: not sure how a normal user would join the root group without a superuser doing that. And if a superuser makes such mistake, all bets are off. There's for example a good chance that person is already a sudoer then and can access the file regardless. I consider it security by obscurity, but YMMV.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant with "regular user joins by mistake the root group". My case is that a superuser could (although chances are slim) put him/her in the root group by mistake. While a 000 permission will allow only root to access the file. I recognize that's probably a edge case, but I consider this way much cleaner also since the comment file ends up having the same permissions as `/etc/shadow`.

Answer (score 3):

Of course you have changes to your `/etc/shadow`.  You don't **want** the account information in `/etc/shadow` on your server - hashed passwords, account expirations, etc - to be a byte-for-byte copy of the upstream `/etc/shadow`.

And I hope you're not overwriting your current `/etc/shadow` with whatever you're getting from your upstream data source.