# Is a comment line allowed in /etc/passwd

Tags: passwd

I know, in RHEL 7.8, that you can have blank lines in `/etc/passwd`

But can you have comment lines, and if so what would the line start with?

Comment: Why would there need to be comments in `/etc/passwd/`? It's not a good idea to directly edit it anyway.

Comment: See also [How do I put comments in my /etc/shadow file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/206730/86440)

Answer (score 8):

The musl C library routines for processing the account database, `getpwent()` et al., do not permit any sort of commentary in the `/etc/passwd` or `/etc/shadow` files.
[The library code](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/passwd/getpwent_a.c#n19) simply does not treat any character as a comment introducer.
(It also does not recognize a `+` line as a YP flag or permit any special markers at all.)

If you have *any* programs built against the musl C library, do not attempt adding comments to these files.

The GNU C library and FreeBSD C library, however, both *do* permit commentary.

Or, rather:

[The GNU C library code providing the `files` sources of all NSS databases](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=nss/nss_files/files-XXX.c#l176) (see the `nsswitch.conf` manual) permits line comments with a `#` as the first non-whitespace character.
So more than just `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow` can contain comments.

On the BSDs, the `/etc/passwd` file *is not* the account database.
On the BSDs the account database *is not* a flat file database, but is a Berkeley DB file (two, in fact, `/etc/pwd.db` and `/etc/spwd.db`), which by the nature of Berkeley DB files does not permit commentary.
`/etc/master.passwd` is *compiled into* the account database(s) by the `pwd_mkdb` tool.

The `/etc/passwd` file on the BSDs is a dummy backwards-compatibility file emitted by `pwd_mkdb`, not actually used for lookups by C library routines and there only for people with shell scripts using direct `awk /etc/passwd` and the like, rather than the better `getent passwd` command (which wraps the C library for shell scripts).

On FreeBSD and its derivatives, [`/etc/master.passwd` can contain comments](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/usr.sbin/pwd_mkdb/pwd_mkdb.c#L569) and the `pwd_mkdb` tool [copies commentary through from `/etc/master.passwd` to `/etc/passwd`](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/usr.sbin/pwd_mkdb/pwd_mkdb.c#L465), without putting it into the main Berkeley DB files.
The `#` can optionally be preceded by exactly only TAB and SPC characters, which is not *quite* the same as the GNU C library (which allows any whitespace character that satisfies `isspace()` in the locale of the process using the GNU C library routines, which is probably a very obscure it-is-sometimes-a-comment-sometimes-a-secret-superuser-record bug waiting to happen).

OpenBSD's and NetBSD's `pwd_mkdb` commands, in contrast, do not allow for commentary in `/etc/master.passwd` and do not insert comments into the dummy `/etc/passwd`.

So you can use `#` comments preceded by TAB and SPC in `/etc/master.passwd` on FreeBSD; and `#` comments precended by the current locale's `isspace()` characters in `/etc/passwd`, `/etc/shadow`, and a whole bunch of other NSS sources on Linux-based operating systems as long as all (relevant) programs are linked against the GNU C library.

Answer (score 3):

Only user entries are allowed in `/etc/passwd`, anything else is considered malformed and causes some tools that depend on this file to fail.

TLDR: No

Answer (score 2):

Each record in `/etc/passwd` describes one user account and comment lines are not supported.

See `passwd(5)` (`man 5 passwd`) for the file format.