# How do you change your username in Manjaro?

Tags: users, rename, manjaro

How do you change your username in Manjaro Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based from this answer in the [Manjaro Forum](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/howto-change-username/16794):

Logoff. Switch to a tty console (`Ctrl+Alt+F4`).

Login as `root`.

Edit `/etc/passwd`. Replace username. Remember to save file.

```
nano /etc/passwd
```

Edit `/etc/shadow`. Replace username. Remember to save file.

```
nano /etc/shadow
```

Edit `/etc/group`. Replace username. Remember to save file.

```
nano /etc/group
```

Finally, rename your current home folder

```
mv /home/oldusername /home/newusername
```

Reboot.

```
reboot
```

Comment: [Why should you NEVER edit the /etc/shadow file directly?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/190241/72456)

Answer (score 0):

I did that and now when I log in, I just see my mouse..

When I entered tty console again and did pwd, it had shown /home/myoldusername even after I did mv /home/oldusername /home/newusername.

But it is always same.

It is possible, that it is my second hdd drive which is mounted to /home?

Thank you

Comment: This should be a comment to the previous answer. Said answers lacked the fact that /etc/passwd must also have the homedir updated.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/425511)