# Change Shadow Password

Tags: shadow

I am looking for a `sed` command to change the line:

```
userA:$6$lhkjhl$sdlfhlmLMHQSDFM374FGSDFkjfh/7mD/354dshkKHQSkljhsd.sdmfjlk57HJ/:95170::::::
```

to

```
userA:$6$sLdkjf$576sdKUKJGKmlk565oiuljkljpi/9Fg/rst3587zet324etze.dsfgLIMLmdf/:34650::::::
```

Comment: Is this hard-coded? Or are the changes you want in a bash variable?

Comment: [Why you should never edit /etc/shadow by hand](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/190241/why-should-you-never-edit-the-etc-shadow-file-directly)

Comment: @Blacksilver its a hard coded

Comment: @Zachary Brady  i will put it on a script to change the password for the same user on many servers

Comment: @Med I would [use the passwd command to script mass password changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714915/using-the-passwd-command-from-within-a-shell-script)

Comment: @Zachary Brady i had proposed the passwd command with EOF entry in my script but my manager refuse because he want me to use sed instead of password to avoid to put password in clear

Comment: On Linux, you can use `chpasswd -e` to give it the already-encrypted password.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

instead:

```
chpasswd -e <<< 'userA:yourencryptedpassword'
```

If you were going to use `sed` - despite the risks:

To set a password - no matter what it was before:

```
sed -i.sedbackup 's/^\(userA:\)[^:]*\(:.*\)$/\1yournewpassword\2/' /etc/shadow
```

To replace a specific password string:

```
sed -i.sedbackup 's/^\(userA:\)youroldpassword\(:.*\)$/\1yournewpassword\2/' /etc/shadow
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the **sed** command you should do this:

```
usermod -p 'encrypted pw' user
```